# Ionic scroll with keyboard on desktop

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Is there way to scroll on desktop browser with PC keyboard up and down?

`<ion-content scroll="true"></ion-content>`

This works with mouse but not with keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

Turns out there is a defined css from ionic.

`<ion-content class="overflow-scroll" scroll="true"></ion-content>`

in case someone needs this!